# Firebase Authentication with whitelisted email addresses

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Assuming a teacher/student scenario what would be a good way to handle 'email invitations'?

Using a CSV upload I would like to create users or a whitelist of emails that will restrict everyone else (not invited) from creating an account.

Should I create my own login form that will check the whitelist first and then create the user?

Is there some type of BeforeAuth hook? LOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'd recommend is to separate the auth from the access by using [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). Allow any one to create a user, but [attach a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) to the user create event. If the user matches one on the white list, set a [custom user claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) (this just launched recently!)

Finally, in your rules, check for that use property before giving access to the data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "adminContent": {
      ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
      ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically I would allow them to create an account but then use onCreate to check and delete the account if they are not on the whitelist.

Comment: That would work too, but I'm suggesting here that you use onCreate to annotate the user, and then control access to the content you want to restrict based on that annotation. Otherwise you have some gap of time where they can access it (after the user is created and before the function completes). The annotation route only gives them access when they've been OK'd

Comment: I have written a sample code based on @IanBarber suggestion: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/firebase/setup-firebase-authentication-with-vuejs/

Answer (score 3):

FirebaseAuth is only meant to verify that a person is who he/she say they are. It does not restrict usage.

See [FirebaseAuth documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)

> After a successful sign in, you can access the user's basic profile
>   information, and you can control the user's access to data stored in
>   other Firebase products. You can also use the provided authentication
>   token to verify the identity of users in your own backend services

I.e. you can use Firebase Authentication to verify a user is who they say they are, but restricting them from your services is then up to you based on the information in their user profile information

You can however combine FirebaseAuth with other Firebase services like Database or Storage which are integrated with auth. But for your scenario you still need to create the logic to restrict authenticated users from accessing data they shouldn't be able to access using Rules in the database or in storage. You haven't specified much else in your question so I can't give a better answer for now

Comment: Yes, I can have teachers upload 'user profiles' into Firebase and yes, once authenticated I know that I will need to have Rules setup to restrict access.

I'm simply looking for a smart way to handle account creation. I'm trying to keep just anyone from creating an account but I'd like the students to be notified and allow them to create their own passwords